# Integer enters if while cond is false in java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);   
    int n = in.nextInt();

    if(n >= 2 || n <= 10){
                ...
    }
    else{ ... }
}
```

This is a sample code of the problem I'm facing.
When I pass the value 1 or 11 even though the condition is false program still enters
If statement , while it should enter else.

Comment: You are using `OR`. `11` is not `<=10`, but it's `>=2`

Comment: this condition is always true.

Comment: you need to make condition when n >= 2 AND n <= 10 not OR

Comment: because you are using '||' operator, it won't matter what is written on the right side of OR operator if left side is true. So because 11>=2 which is true, the short-circuit will happen and if condition will be executed.

Comment: "even though the condition is false" have you tested? Kind of hard to believe that Java is that wrong executing `if-else` statements - they are *essential*. Add `System.out.println(n >= 2 || n <= 10);` and test with some values

Answer (score 6):

```
if (n >= 2 || n <= 10)
```

is always true.

You need:

```
if (n >= 2 && n <= 10)
```

i.e. n >= 2 AND n <= 10.

Comment: I'm curious... can you demonstrate/prove that it's "always" true?

Comment: @ernest_k what do you need to prove? `n` is an `int`. All `int`s are always either larger than or equal to 2 OR lower than or equal to 10.

Comment: @ernest_k I'm not sure what you mean by "demonstrated". Are you asking for some formal proof? The set of `int`s that satisfy n>=2 is all the `int`s between 2 and Integer.MAX_VALUE. The set of `int`s that satisfy n<=10 is all the `int`s between Integer.MIN_VALUE and 10. The union of these two sets is equal to the set of all `int` values.

Comment: @ernest_k Well we could start with `n >= 2 || n <= 2`.  By observation, this covers all integers, positive or negative.  Then, we can add one to the inequality on the right to get `n >= 2 || n <= 3`.  Again, by observation, we haven't changed the range of numbers covered from 2 higher, _nor_ have we changed the range of numbers from 2 lower.  We could formalize this in a mathematical proof, but why bother?

Comment: Thanks guys. Sure that's proof enough... I feared I was trusting the intuition a little too fast (and yes, inequalities weren't my thing).

Comment: @ernest_k can you prove it is not "always" true? that is, there is some condition it is false? (disregarding the abrupt ending of virtual machine or program - like e.g. someone turning computer off)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger No, I can't: because I know it's true. I just wanted to have something more than that intuitive knowing (from just looking at it).

Answer (score 0):

|| :-It represent OR condition so if any one of the conditions is true then it enters the loop.
&& :- It represent AND condition so if both of the conditions is true then it enters the loop.
Logical operators are used in various ways.